# codeigniter pagination not work for particular user articles

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My Pagination not work , In this case simple print users article to match the rc code of users its work perfectly url is ../project/article/user_article/?rc=4715422 , its work but pagintion url not print any article, pagination url is ../project/article/user_article/?rc=4715422/1,
here is my code: controller code is -

```
  public function user_article()
{   

    $rc=$_GET['rc'];
    $data['title'] = "User Article";
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . 'article/user_article/?rc='. $rc ;
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->article_m->record_count_uarticles($_GET);
    $config["per_page"] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->article_m->fetch_result_uarticles($_GET, $config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    if ($this->session->userdata ('is_logged_in')){
        $data['profile']=$this->model_users->profilefetch();
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('user_article', $data);
        $this->load->view('sfooter', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('signin');
    }

}
```

and my modal is :

```
  public function record_count_uarticles($rc) {
        $query=$this->db->select('email,writer')->where('rc',$rc['rc'])->get('users');
        $result=$query->result_array();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row_array(); 
            $array = array ('email' => $row['email'], 'status' => '1'); 
            return $this->db->where($array)->count_all_results("articles");
        }
    }

    public function fetch_result_uarticles($rc, $limit, $start) {

        $query=$this->db->select('email,writer')->where('rc',$rc['rc'])->get('users');
        $result=$query->result_array();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row_array();
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $array = array ('u.email' => $row['email'], 'a.status' => '1', 'u.writer' => '1');  
            $query1=$this->db->select('a.id,title,a.status,description,image,a.email,tags,postdate,firstname,lastname,rc')->join('users u','u.email = a.email','left')->where($array)->order_by('a.id', 'DESC')->get('articles a');

            if ($query1->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query1->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Check this code, pagination show properly,  first page article print correctly but after click on pagination link then no article print in scnd page

This Link work but default link is not work , is there any query to change the url

../project/article/user_article/?rc=4715422/1   -- Default Link Not Work

../project/article/user_article/1/?rc=4715422 -- Custom Edited Link work

Comment: http://localhost/ only exists on your local network. We cannot access those urls.

Comment: yes ill just show that url its not working in your machine

Comment: bro is there any way to chenage the location of number in pagination url like this  : ../project/article/user_article/1/?rc=4715422 by defualt pagintion link is :  ../project/article/user_article/?rc=4715422/1

Comment: I see you are using query strings but do not have that enabled on pagination `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;`

Comment: This Code work but in second page same article show

Comment: please answer me why same article show in every page